# Scrollbar value not updating when using mousescroll

Tags: c#, winforms

I am dynamically adding buttons to a FlowLayoutPanel, when I scroll using the mouse wheel on the panel the scrollbar value does not change however it still scrolls. When I click on the small arrow to force a scroll the value changes.

I want an event to trigger whenever the value of the scrollbar changes but can't seem to figure out how to, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an oversight by the authors.  Not sure what you are doing with the scroll values, but you can just use the MouseWheel event to get the same scroll value:

```
void flowLayoutPanel1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  this.Text = flowLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Value.ToString();
}
```